# Android Glide: Use same bitmap for transformation

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I have a grid. Each item has 2 ImageViews. Loaded image is the same for both ImageViews, but in one ImageView I want to apply a transformation to bitmap.
Can I load original bitmap only one time and cache both original and transformed bitmap (for both Imageviews) ?

```
private DrawableRequestBuilder<String> mFullRequest;
private DrawableRequestBuilder<String> mBlurRequest;
...

//in my adapter constructor
mFullRequest = Glide.with(context)
        .fromString()
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .priority(Priority.HIGH)
        .crossFade(R.anim.fade_in, 150);
mBlurRequest = Glide.with(context)
        .fromString()
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
        .transform(new BlurredImageTransformation(context))
        .crossFade();

.....
//in getview
final String imgUrl =.....
mFullRequest
        .load(imgUrl)
        .into(holder.campaignImage);

mBlurRequest
        .load(imgUrl)
        .override(Constants.MAX_BLURRED_IMAGE_WIDTH, (int) (Constants.MAX_BLURRED_IMAGE_WIDTH * ratio))
        .into(holder.blurredImage);
```

Comment: You would probably have to apply the transformation, and then save / cache the result. Note that reading something from storage may actually take _longer_ than applying the  transformation again.

Comment: With current implementation both bitmap are stored (Simple and transformed), but the problem is that image is downloaded 2 times. I want to download the bitmap only 1 time

Comment: Then you have to download the image using your own code, and then either save it to file or into memory, and then tell  the image loading / processing library you are using  to load it from disk or from memory instead of downloading it twice.